# Why is my compiler complaining that this isn't a class or namespace?

Tags: c++, qt, header-files

I'm attempting to write a Minesweeper game in QT but I'm getting stopped cold at every step.  Presently the QT Creator is complaining about the following code:

```
> #include <QApplication>
  #include "mainwindow.h"
  #include "sweepermodel.h"
  #include <iostream>
  #include <QTime>
  #include <string>

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
      QApplication a(argc, argv);
      SweeperModel *sweeperModel = new SweeperModel(16, 16, 40);
      sweeperModel->gameState = SweeperModel::GAME_STATE::Playing;
      MainWindow w;
      w.show();

      return a.exec();
  }
```

It states that:

> "C:\Users\nthexwn\Workspace\AISweeper\main.cpp:12: error: 'SweeperModel::GAME_STATE' is not a class or namespace"

Referring back to the SweeperModel header file we can see that the GAME_STATE is indeed an enum which was declared there:

```
#ifndef SWEEPERMODEL
#define SWEEPERMODEL

#include <vector>
#include "sweepernode.h"

// Abstraction of the game grid as a 1-dimensional vector along with a flag
// indicating game state.
class SweeperModel
{
public:

// Possible game states from a player's perspective.
enum GAME_STATE
{
    Loading,
    Error_Height,
    Error_Width,
    Error_Mines,
    Playing,
    Lost,
    Won,
    Exiting,
};

GAME_STATE gameState;
short height;
short width;
short mines;

int getRandomValue(int low, int high);
void assignMinesToModel(SweeperModel *sweeperModel);
SweeperModel(short height, short width, short mines);
~SweeperModel();
SweeperNode& getNode(short row, short column);

private:
    std::vector<SweeperNode*> nodes;
};

#endif // SWEEPERMODEL
```

What am I forgetting here?  How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, enum doesn't create a namespace, so your code shoule be

```
sweeperModel->gameState = SweeperModel::Playing;
```

second, c++11 recommands enum class, like

```
enum class enum_name{ firstone, secondone, thirdone};
```

if you add the keyword "class" behind the "enum", it also works well.
At last, the MSVC will treat the enums like they have namespace automatically, so your codes will work well also in MSVC;